EF Core CountAsync() doesn't work while Count() works
Trying to build a repository which handled paged requests. Strangely, CountAsync() doesn't work while Count() works normally. The process ends abruptly with no immediate exception thrown.
var query = _context.TableName
                    .AsQueryable();

query = query.ApplyOrdering(queryObj, columnsMap);

// This doesn't work, disposes DbContext and exits
result.TotalItems = await query.CountAsync(); 

query = query.ApplyPaging(queryObj);
result.Items = await query.ToListAsync();


var query = _context.TableName
                    .AsQueryable();

query = query.ApplyOrdering(queryObj, columnsMap);
result.TotalItems = query.Count();   // Works

query = query.ApplyPaging(queryObj);
result.Items = query.ToList();       // Works

Any idea what could cause this?
Thanks

Have you turned on "break when thrown" for all exceptions just before you execute the line?

How is this code being called? Sounds like someone isn't awaiting somewhere up the chain.

What does your ApplyOrdering do?  Does it return IQueryable?  Is the calling method also async and awaited?

@Kevin yes ApplyOrdering is returning IQueryable, and awaited by the caller

@Charlieface it is being awaited.

So you claim, but if it was then the context wouldn't be disposed. I suggest you double/triple check that.

How decleared method body? not async void?

@Charlieface the moment CountAsync() executes, the dispose function is called

@SvyatoslavDanyliv : it is public async Task<List>

Then put a breakpoint on the Dispose (override it if you need to do that) and see what the stack trace is. Check at the same time if there is a $exception in the Watch Window, because it may be an uncaught exception unravelling the stack.

I found the issue, the parent call was from an Azure Event which wasn't being awaited.
@Charlieface you were right :)
Thanks for the help everyone
